# How to undo an -R status (marked for deletion) in SVN

Tags: svn

I'm trying to add a_folder to SVN but I accidentally scheduled my root directory for deletion:

```
[phil@sessions www]$svn status
R      .
A      a_folder
```

I can't commit a_folder's adding because...

```
[phil@sessions www]$ svn commit a_folder-m "adding"
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: '/home/phil/www' is not under version control and is not part of the commit, yet its child '/home/phil/www/a_folder' is part of the commit
```

If I try "svn add ." I get "www is already under version control".  How can I remove this status so that I can go on with my life?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`svn revert .`

Comment: You might also need -R if you have a whole hierarchy of subdirectories/subfolders. So "svn revert . -R"

Answer (score 2):

My problem was in a single folder, so I resolve in this way:

```
cd Project
svn revert Folder
cd Folder
svn add --force .
cd .. && svn commit -m "resolved svn inconsistency"
```

**[Here](http://gotofritz.net/blog/howto/svn-status-codes/)** a usefull link with the list of all status.